# ANTLRWorks warning 'no start rule'

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

please help a newbie to understand this 
warning in ANTLWorks:

> [11:10:15] warning(138): BooleanExpr.g:0:1: grammar BooleanExpr: no start rule (no rule can obviously be followed by EOF)

This is how definition of my grammar looks like:

```
grammar BooleanExpr;
booleanExpr
    :   andExpr ('OR' andExpr)*;
andExpr :   notExpr (('AND' | ' ' ) notExpr)*;
notExpr :   kppExpr ('NOT' kppExpr);
kppExpr :   keywordExpr|phraseExpr|proximityExpr|'(' booleanExpr ')';
keywordExpr
    :CHAR+;
phraseExpr
    :   '"' keywordExpr '"';
proximityExpr
    :   keywordExpr|phraseExpr '~' INT;
CHAR    :   ('A'..'Z') | ('a'..'z');
INT :   '0'..'9'+;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Any grammar needs so-called start rule. Start rule is a rule that is not referenced by another rule. If your grammar does not have such rule, ANTLR generator will issue a warning:

```
no start rule (no rule can obviously be followed by EOF)
```

To avoid it, add a dummy start rule to your grammar:

```
start_rule: someOtherRule;
```

Comment: Is "start_rule" supposed to be a magic hard-coded value? Adding that rule did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Normally parsers are written to parse an entire input (from the beginning to the end of a file). Grammars used for this task generally include a rule like the following.

```
compilationUnit : someElement* EOF;
```

This rule says a compilation unit is a sequence of zero-or-more elements ending at the end of the file. If the `EOF` reference is omitted, you could have a rule like the following.

```
compilationUnit : someElement*;
```

The problem with this form lies in its error handling ability. If the input contains a syntax error, then rather than trying to correct and/or recover from it, the rule will simply return (an empty sequence is a valid interpretation of this `compilationUnit` rule, so that is preferred to a longer sequence containing an invalid element).

ANTLRWorks is informing you that the grammar does not contain a rule ending with an explicit `EOF` reference, which can be problematic if you are intending to parse complete files.

Comment: I do not plan to parse files, my intent here is validate boolean expressions that will be stored as a String objects. It doesn't make sense for me to append EOF in the end of the rule.
How error handling could be supported in this case?

Comment: If you plan you parse an entire string, then treat it like a file and add `EOF` to the end of the start rule.

Comment: Alright, should i append EOF symbol to the end of the String as well?

Comment: @IhorM. No. `EOF` simply means the end of the input, which in your case is the end of the string.